# Citrix website automation with selenium or similars

Tags: python, selenium, automation, puppeteer, citrix

Is there any way to use selenium or something similar on citrix web systems?

I am currently using pyautogui but it is being very ineffective on its own. If you know how to improve pyautogui I also accept tips.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to run your automation and debug at the same time, then it is going to be challenging to use stand-alone Citrix apps and use Selenium or Puppeteer.

Can you use a full Citrix Virtual desktop with your apps installed? That would allow you debug more effectively.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).